# save load text file ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to save and load some history to text file

I use this code

```
    - (void) saveHistory {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];

        [resultWindow.text writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];  

    }

    - (void) loadHistory {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
    if (resultWindow.text == nil) {

        resultText = @"";
        resultWindow.text = resultText;
    }
        resultWindow.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    }
```

File save ok! But when I load `resultWindow.text` is empty (0x00000000)

Comment: Have you verified that resultWindow is not nil?

Comment: I update post but that not result((

Comment: You need to check resultWindow, not resultWindow.text.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of these cases where doing some simple error checking might really help you out.  What I'm showing here might be a bit too much, but at the same time, error checking almost *always* can help the programmer come up with better performance.

```
- (void) saveHistory {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];

    if(resultWindow)
    {
        if(filePath)
        {
            NSError * error = NULL;
            BOOL success = [resultWindow.text writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
            if(success == NO)
            {
                // success would be NO if the file did *not* get successfully written out
                NSLog( @"error in writing file to %@ - %@", filePath, [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog( @"filePath is mysteriously null");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog( @"why is resultWindow null during saveHistory??");
    }
}

- (void) loadHistory {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];

    if(resultWindow)
    {
        if(filePath)
        {
            NSError * error = NULL;
            resultWindow.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
            if(resultWindow.text == NULL)
            {
                NSLog( @"error in reading file from %@ - %@", filePath, [error localizedDescription]);)
            }
        } else {
            NSLog( @"filePath is mysteriously null");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog( @"why is resultWindow null during loadHistory??");
    }
}
```

Comment: if I paste this code in result log @"why is resultWindow null during loadHistory??"

Comment: Well, it looks like "`resultWindow`" is null. You need to figure out why that is happening. My guess is that your "`resultWindow`" outlet is not connected (or the view not loaded) when you call "`loadHistory`".